# math.sqrt problem in C

Tags: c

Why is the following code throwing me an error **undefined reference to sqrt**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double i = 25;
    printf("\nSquare root of %d = %d",i,sqrt(i));
    return 0;
}
```

I have included **math.h** and I am using Debian.Can anyone tell me what is going wrong .Do i need to install my libraries again or something?

Comment: please include the full and exact error message.   It will help indicate if it is a compiler or linker problem.  Also, open up math.h, and see for yourself if sqrt is in there.

Comment: Change the modifiers - sqrt returns double, and you`ve used int modifiers for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using GCC? Any "undefined reference" means that there is a linking error. In other words, you aren't properly linking to a library that contains the function that it is complaining about. In this case, I believe you can add -lm to your linker flags to link to the math lib.

Answer (score 7):

Compile it with the -lm flag on the command line to link to the math library.

Answer (score 3):

The math functions are not linked by default on Linux (since they are comparatively seldom used). You need to add

```
-lm
```

to your compiler line to link to libm.so, the math library.

Comment: aren't Linux for the tech-savvy?  then shouldn't the math library be essential rather than rarely used?

Comment: The reason why the math library is not linked by default is not that the functions are "seldom used"; they're actually used more frequently than many other parts of the libc.  The actual reasons are mostly historical curiosities at this point.  Essentially, users were historically more likely to want to use alternative implementations of the math library than other parts of libc.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: sqrt(), sin() and log() used more frequently used than malloc(), printf(), or memcpy()? I don't think so. But you are right, the ability to use alternative implementations is another reason why the math functions are not lumped together with libc. (Especially in the beginning, where not every computer *had* a FPU, and emulation libraries differed widely in their performance and / or precision.) Note that this isn't mandated by the language standard, but an implementation detail on Unixes.

Comment: @動靜能量: Been coding C/C++ professionally for a decade now, and haven't touched `<math.h>` but once in that time.

Comment: `sqrt( )` used more than `memcpy( )` and `printf( )`? No, of course not (except for those of us who write numerical code for a living).  Used more than `wcspbrk( )`? Absolutely.